# PHP MySQL multiple conditions in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with some records and columns: "type", "id" and others. I would like to select all records with any "type" that's mentioned in array $typearray but without records which id's are in $idarray. I tried to do something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db 
    WHERE type IN('".implode("','",$typearray)."') 
    AND id NOT IN('".implode("','",$idarray)."') 
    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

But it doesn't seem to work - the:

```
type IN('".implode("','",$typearray)."')
```

condition works fine but the second does not. At first I thought the issue was with column types - both arrays contains strings, "type" column is a VARCHAR(10) and id is INT, but changing it to string didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

If I print a query I get this:

```
SELECT * FROM db 
WHERE type IN('apple','tomato','potato') 
AND id NOT IN('20','1','10','15','8') 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
```

The first condition works fine: it selects only apples, tomatoes and potatoes. The second condition does nothing and even if I type manually:

```
id NOT IN('20','1','10','15','8')
```

or

```
id NOT IN('20,1,10,15,8')
```

or

```
id NOT IN(20,1,10,15,8)
```

it still fails.

**EDIT2:**

Actually forget it. I'm an idiot. I've mixed up my variables a bit...

Comment: just `var_dump` the query before executing it. then you can see whats going wrong. :)

Comment: give the query how is it forming?

Comment: MySQL doesn't care wether you put an integer into quotationmarks or not. IS `$idarray` really an array? Before `$result` line, put `assert(is_array($typearray)); assert(is_array($idarray));`.

Comment: Please show the generated query.

Comment: typeArray doens't have a type that contains an apostrophe does it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this query, or at least do a `echo $result, "\n";`, into mysql workbench to see what it give.

And I'd say the default behavior to have when a query does not work: first in Mysql Workbench (or any SQL runner like Toad, Squirrel ...)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db 
    WHERE type IN('".implode("','",$typearray)."') 
    AND id NOT IN('".implode("','",$idarray)."') 
    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

If `$typearray` is empty, you are looking for `type IN ('')`, which might never matches.
If `$idarray` is empty, you are looking for `id not in ('')` which might always matches.

And if `$typearray` or `$idarray` contains invalid character, you will get an error.

[edit] by the way, if `$typearray` or `$idarray` may contains invalid character, you might use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php) and [mysqli_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysqli-escape-string.php):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db 
    WHERE type IN('".implode("','", array_map('mysql_escape_string', $typearray))."') 
    AND id NOT IN('".implode("','", array_map('mysql_escape_string', $idarray))."') 
    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to escape integer variables:

```
...
AND id NOT IN(" . implode(",", $idarray).") 
...
```